# What's the purpose of requiring ejs?

Tags: node.js, ejs, node-modules, templating

In many code examples for ejs, I see code like this:

```js
// ...
const ejs = require('ejs');
// ...
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
// ...
```

But it seems like the constant `ejs` is never used. Then what's the purpose of requiring it?

It doesn't seem to make any difference when I choose to require or not requiring ejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set ejs template by using: ***app.set('view engine', 'ejs');***

And here we don't require any ejs import.

But situation can come where you to have render some ejs file and then pass on data and do some stuff with this template, then in those scenario you have to require ejs and then use its methods for it. For example:

// Template example for ejs:

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
ejs.renderFile(
path.join(__dirname, '../../views/pages/your_ejs_file.ejs'),
your_data,
);
```

That's just one use case.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `EJS Template Engine` by:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

But you can also use the `ejs` for performing `caching` operation like:

```
const ejs = require('ejs'),
const LRU = require('lru-cache');
ejs.cache = LRU(100); // LRU cache with 100-item limit
```

`EJS` is used to cache the `JS` function used to render templatees. And if want to clear the `EJS` caache you can simply call the `ejs.clearCache`.  This is just an example but you can use `ejs` in many ways. [More about Ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)